# British citizenship with a British father and a Trinidad mother

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizenship

How can I acquire British citizenship if my father is a British citizen? He resides in England, but I was born in the Caribbean in 1981. My parents were not married. Could you provide me with the process of acquiring citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

You are eligible for British Citizenship , provided your father was a British citizen 'other than by descent' (usually this means he was born in the UK). It makes no difference that your parents were not married (thanks to the Immigration Act of 2014 which explicitly grants eligibility to those who would have been eligible if their parents had been married)

This website gives [the application procedure](https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen/overview).

This gives more technical information about [the requirements for British citizenship](http://www.cara-online.org/InformationaboutBritishcitizenship.html).

Comment: This seems incorrect.  The Nationality Act 1948 specifically applies to "legitimate" children, and would have governed the OP's nationality at birth, since the 1981 act did not take effect until 1 January 1983.  From 1 July 2006, children born out of wedlock to a British father before that date can be registered as a British citizen, but only before reaching the age of 18 years.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_British_nationality_law#Children_of_unmarried_British_fathers

Comment: @phoog: It seems that the recently passed Section 65 of the Immigration Act 2014 (which was commenced on April 6, 2015) does allow the OP to register.